# Tensorflow Shuffle Batch - Batch size

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to better understand the behavior of queues and batches. I have 1,000,000 records in my training set and I want to train on batches of 1000. Right now my code is creating a queue using string_input_producer and then doing a read_up_to based on my batch size (in this case 1000). What will be the behavior if I set the batch size in the corresponding shuffle_batch to be smaller? Is it going to throw out the other 900 records or dequeue 100 at a time but still ultimately process all of the records?

```
queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(partitions, 
  num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=shuffle)

_, rows = reader.read_up_to(queue, num_records=1000)

features = tf.parse_example(rows, features=input_features)

features = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      features,
      batch_size=100,
      capacity=10000,
      min_after_dequeue=2001,
      num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
      enqueue_many=True,
      allow_smaller_final_batch=True
  )
```

Comment: maybe you can have a try

Comment: @YuwenYan I have tried it when I was attempting to speed up the dequeueing process which was causing me a significant bottleneck. Things sped up a substantial amount which made me suspicious that it wasn't processing all the records which spurred this question. Is there a way for me to tell what exactly is happening and how many records are getting processed?